# java.library.path not set as LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, catalina, library-path

I'm running apache tomcat on a Linux machine hosted on google cloud, standard machine without anything fancy.

The machine host's back_end Java API business application which requires certain binary .so files to link to when running.

The required libraries are added to $LD_LIBRARRY_PATH

But when i run tomcat, java.library.path does not include this, and i get the error:

> 31-May-2022 11:20:16.378 INFO [main]
> jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke The Apache
> Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the
> java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-li
> nux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]

Im out of ideas, how do i setjava.library.path includes $LD_LIBRARY_PATH when java runs ?

Krgds.

MORE INFO:

running from commandline:

`java -XshowSettings:properties`

gives:

```
  java.library.path = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux
    /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib
    /usr/java/packages/lib
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/jni
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

But when tomcat/catalina, runs it tels:

```
was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-li
nux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
```

Comment: I think `java.library.path` is sometimes not set, so why not included it explicitly in your OPTS? `-Djava.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/extra/libraries`

Comment: I wonder if you only set it without `export`?

Comment: Thanks!

@g00se: could be, where ? In catalina.sh ?

Comment: Could be TOMCAT_OPTS but check for your version, as Tomcat has the habit of changing all the time

Comment: Like:

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

??

Comment: JAVA_OPTS could still be a thing, but as I said, check for your version

Comment: I'm using /opt/apache-tomee-plus-9.0.0-M3 , so as i understand it's CATALINA_OPTS, but not sure how to add it...

when i run:
 java -XshowSettings:properties
from commandline, eveything looks fine, and the paths are included, 

But when is start Catalina, it's not considered, it seems to default and exclude my libs ?

Comment: *eveything looks fine* Can you post that output in code tags please? (JUst the bit that includes `java.library.path`)

Comment: Yes! I have added the output, at the end of original question, above